# any one please explain me what is the exact use of 'j_spring_security_check' in spring security and how it works

Tags: spring-security

am trying to implement the code using spring security with database there I found this topic but seriously i didn't understand this concept.why they add post method within this 'j_spring_security_check' 
so please anyone explain me with example.

Comment: You need to post your HTML login form somewhere. In old Spring Security Web the URL was by default defined as `/j_spring_security_check`. I believe that in the newer versions it is simply `/login`. http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-form Be careful that many online tutorials and articles are quite dated.

Answer (score 1):

It's a preconfigured URL in spring security to authenticate via form input.

It can be configured in your spring security configuration to point to another URL if needed.

If a form submits to this URL it needs to have the relevant parameters for the `AuthenticationManager` to use, such as `j_username` and `j_password`

These were changed in later versions to use `username` and `password`.

The best example of this using Spring MVC is in the [Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5//hellomvc.html).